# Media Type versioning in Accept header for ReST

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, content-type, http-accept-header

I have added versioning for the media types (xml/json) supported in my ReST services. The Accept header of the incoming request should have a media type with valid version to get a proper response in the specified format. The problem is that if the request contains **a valid data format** in the accept header but **an invalid version** (or no version specified) I have to give error response in that particular data format.

For example, let the valid media types be **application/xml+v2** and **application/json+v2**. If the request header contains only **application/xml** or **application/xml+v1** I have to give error response in **xml** and if the header contains **application/json+v1** I have to give error response in **json**.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to provide custom error message in case of wrong (unsupported) media type? Isn't it enough to use proper HTTP error code: `415 Unsupported Media Type` and leave body of response empty?

In case if media type doesn't contain version I will assume that client request the newest available version.

Comment: I have to provide a custom error response. Currently I have a bean entry in rest-servlet.xml corresponding to each supported type with suitable converter. This can be given for each valid versioned media type. For all others I've included a wildcard entry into one of the converters. So whether it is **application/xml+v2** or **application/json+v2** the response obtained will be according to the converter.